# Auto submit a form on load with angularJs, but only if valid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, submit

Let's say I have a form in my DOM, and this form is filled via angular ngModels and values from the query string.

Then, I would like to auto submit the form at launch, but only if the form is valid (after been filled so).

I thought about watching both ngFormController properties `$pristine` and `$valid` to become both true and then submit the form. But these properties are already set to true from the beginning, so no way to distinguish a valid form from an invalid.

In fact, I should submit the form only if the watch function is not called twice, which is really nuts! 
Please have a look to the [jsFiddle I called "how I failed" :)](http://jsfiddle.net/msieurtoph/e9ahm3Lh/)

I know I can solve the pb using a `$timeout` and check the properties after few milliseconds (*so please do not post this solution*), but I am asking for a nicer solution.

Does somebody have an idea? Is there any callback function called after form has been filled for the first time or when the form comes to a stable state ?

Thx a lot.